# Angularjs click propagation to parents

Tags: javascript

First of all I would like to say that I'm new to angularjs, so if I make a mistake please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
 <div ng-click="upper($event)">
    <label class="checkbox" ng-click="clickLabel($event)">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel">
        <span class="checkbox__face" ng-click="clickFace($event)"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
```

And my javascript is:

```
$scope.$watch('checkboxModel', (newValue) => {
            console.log('checkboxModel changed', newValue)
        });

        $scope.clickLabel = ($event) => {
            console.log('clickLabel', $event.srcElement)
        }

        $scope.upper = ($event) => {
            console.log('upper', $event.srcElement);
        }

        $scope.clickFace = ($event) => {
            $event.stopPropagation();
            console.log('clickFace', $event.srcElement);
        }
```

The ouput is:
[Outpu 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrJVR.jpg)

If I remove the `$event.stopPropagation();` from the clickFace function my output is : [Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9WxN.jpg)

My question is why does the event propagation does not stop when I use the stopPropagation function ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly ...

Try with `stopImmediatePropagation()` :

```
$scope.clickFace = ($event) => {
    $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('clickFace', $event.srcElement);
}
```

**stopPropagation** will prevent any parent handlers from being executed.

**stopImmediatePropagation** will prevent any parent handlers and also any other handlers from executing